# Is the canvas.getContext('2d').arc() method centered?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I noticed that I don't need to offset circles to center them. Is it autmatically centered? If so, why is it unlike the `rect`, `fillRect`, `fillText`, and `strokeText` methods?(These all have to be offset to be centered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a full `arc()` (i.e a circle) will be centered to the `x` and `y` parameters you pass to it. These two parameters define the *origin* of the ellipse that will get drawn.

You are right, it is quite different than the `rect()` (and its *fill / stroke* equivalents) method, which is actually a shorthand for

```
lineTo(x, y);
lineTo(x + width, y);
lineTo(x + width, y + height);
lineTo(x, y + height);
lineTo(x, y);
```

So we could say the origin of the *rect* method will be its top-left corner, just like it is for *drawImage* and *putImageData* methods.

But `fillText()` origin for one can be controlled by setting `textAlign`, and `textBaseline` properties of your context, so this one is quite different.

And for other path methods, they use control points, so the notion of an origin doesn't really apply there.

```js
var x = 250;
var y = 100;
var txt = ['click to redraw the rect', 'using the long-hand version'];

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '14px sans-serif';
var w = ctx.measureText(txt[1]).width;
// fillText origin can be set
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.fillText(txt[0], x, y - 8);
ctx.fillText(txt[1], x, y + 8);
// rect / strokeRect / fillRect is top-left
ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, 16);
// arc is x,y
ctx.arc(x, y, w / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();
// show that rect is just a shorthand
onclick = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + 16);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + 16);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not automatically centred. Check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) from MDN:

> Parameters: **`x`** The x-axis coordinate of the circle's center

So no, you have to specify it, unless it's on your current path